# Using static initialization to register classes

Tags: c++, c++11

So I read this article about using static initialization to register classes (http://quantumgraphics.blogspot.nl/2014/11/abusing-static-initialization.html). It's exactly what I need so I decided to implement it. I couldn't get it to work however, so I made a little test case to make sure I got the details right. Turns out even a simple example doesn't work (http://ideone.com/HDr8ZM):

```
#include <iostream>

int a = 0;

template<
    class T
>
class Scriptable {
protected:
    struct Proxy
    {
        Proxy() {
            std::cout << "Proxy was executed! ID: " << T::id << std::endl;
            a++;
        }
    };
    static Proxy proxy_;
} ;

template<
    class T
>
typename Scriptable<T>::Proxy Scriptable<T>::proxy_;

class Object : public Scriptable<Object> {
public:
    constexpr static auto id = "[Object]";
} ;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Done " << a << std::endl;
}
```

So basically what needs to happen (or more precisely, what I want to happen) is that the Proxy constructor should be executed before main. I want to use the the Proxy constructor to register the class with some singleton base class factory, but I don't think that's related to this code not working.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm probably missing a compiler flag or something (the example should compile with just the -std=c++11 flag). Or is there maybe a better way to do what I'm trying here?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's the missing piece of the puzzle. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Pradhan's link I was able to cook up what I needed:

```
#include <iostream>

int a = 0;

template <typename T, T /*unnamed*/>
struct nnb_ForceInit { };

template<
    class T
>
class Scriptable {
public:
    struct nnb_Proxy {
        nnb_Proxy() {
            std::cout << "Proxy was executed! ID: " << T::id << std::endl;
            a++;
        }
    };

    static nnb_Proxy __nnb_proxy__;
    typedef nnb_ForceInit<nnb_Proxy&, __nnb_proxy__> __nnb_typedef_dummy__;
} ;

template<
    class T
>
typename Scriptable<T>::nnb_Proxy Scriptable<T>::__nnb_proxy__;

class Object : public Scriptable<Object> {
public:
    constexpr static auto id = "[Object]";
};

class Image : public Scriptable<Image> {
public:
    constexpr static auto id = "[Image]";
};

class Error : public Scriptable<Error> {
public:
    constexpr static auto id = "[Error]";
} ;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Done " << a << std::endl;
}
```

I don't have a very clear idea how it works exactly but it seems to do what I want/works fine, so I guess that's it.

Comment: this really works, but the trick is adding nnb_ForceInit, otherwise the compiler won't initialize the static variable __nnb_proxy__

Comment: why wouldn't is initialize it?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because there's no reason for your `Proxy` to ever get constructed. In this case, your `main()` doesn't even construct an `Object` - so why would the `Proxy` get constructed? You'd have to at least do that:

```
int main() {
    Object o;
    std::cout << "Done " << a << std::endl;
}
```

But then, simply constructing `o` doesn't reference the proxy in any way, so there's still no reason for it to be constructed. You'll have to touch it somehow. Simplest is to just reference it in `Scriptable`'s constructor:

```
Scriptable() {
    proxy_; // this line throws a warning, since this line does nothing,
            // so replace it with something reasonable. but this line is
            // enough to force proxy_ to be instantiated.
}
```

If I add those two bits (`Object o;` and the `Scriptable` constructor), then your code yields:

```
Proxy was executed! ID: [Object]
Done 1
```

Another way is to actually declare the `proxy_` within the constructor:

```
Scriptable() {
    static Proxy proxy_;
}
```

Comment: That's bad news - if this would be the only solution it means that the article I linked to is *really* wrong. It doesn't list any of these steps. Luckily, in the duplicate question Pradhan suggested a trick can be found that forces proxy_ to be initialized. I will add the solution in the answers. Thanks for your answer!